# Why am I getting '0' as the return value in my test?

Tags: c, min

I have to write a program that finds the smallest of the five integers in the argument list. Here's my code:

```
int min5(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
   int answer;

   if (a < b && a < c && a < d && a < e)
   {
      answer = a;
   }
   else if (b < a && b < c && b < d && b < e)
   {
      answer = b;
   }
   else if (c < a && c < b && c < d && c < e)
   {
      answer = c;
   }
   else if (d < a && d < b && d < c && d < e)
   {
      answer = d;
   }
   else if (e < a && e < b && e < c && e < d)
   {
      answer = e;
   }
   return answer;
}
```

And here's my test case:

```
void min5_tests(void)
{
   int a, b, c, d, e, result;

   a = 1;
   b = 4;
   c = 2;
   d = 7;

   result = min5(a, b, c, d, e);
   checkit_int(result, 1);
}

int main()
{
   min5_tests();

   return 0;
}
```

When I run my test, it says that the value should be 0 instead of what I expected it to be, 1. I thought my code was right but I guess not. :( I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: `e` is not initialised, add a value to it. What does `checkit_int` do?

Comment: AH! Sorry, didn't see that! Thanks!

Comment: `checkit_int()` almost certainly just checks if its two arguments are equal, printing an error if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you haven't initialised `e` for a start so it will be set to an indeterminate value, possibly zero.

That's also rather ... shall we say, less than elegant code (no offence intended) for finding the minimum, quite aside from the unitialised value that will be returned if all input values are equal (none of the `if` statements will be true). You *could* solve that by using `<=` rather than `<` but it would be substantially more readable with something like:

```
int min5 (int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
    int answer = a;
    if (b < answer) answer = b;
    if (c < answer) answer = c;
    if (d < answer) answer = d;
    if (e < answer) answer = e;
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: AH! I see, sorry, careless mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You don't give e a value. Try setting e = 10;

Comment: Also, what do you do when one or more variables have the same value? For example, if a and b = 0 and c, d, e = 100 then you are in trouble.

Comment: Hmm...good point. If the problem doesn't specify (all they want is the min value of the 5 integers) then...is it okay if I don't take that into consideration?

Comment: @Karen, it depends on whether you think it's okay for the minimum of `{1,1,1,1,1}` to be whatever random value happens to be on the stack when your program runs. I would suspect that would _not_ be acceptable :-) At a _minimum,_ use `<=` rather than `<`.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I see, I'll think about that! Thanks for the help! I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

e is not initialised and also that is a rather, erm, unhealthy code.
Also, your code might have problems if the minimum value is shared by two or more variables.
try intialising answer to one variable and then comparing the the value of answer with every other variable. In other words, no else statements here as it has to compare answer with all the 4 other variables, one at a time.